# SSL using heroku foreman tool

Tags: heroku, foreman, heroku-toolbelt

I have a app on heroku that I need to enforce only-ssl on. I would also like foreman to force ssl, for testing purposes. However, I can't find how to do this, since the ssl layer has to be implemented by foreman, not the app, so as to emulate heroku production servers as closely as possible.

Any ideas for SSL with foreman?

Comment: I realize now that chrome will connect to the local server, but gives "Error code: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR". http:// works just fine (ssl restrictions removed)

Comment: as well as foreman logs giving `ERROR bad Request-Line \`\x16\x03\`... it seems that the server is speaking html to a browser expecting ssl